# How to create a pool of clients that can be assumed by a parallel foreach loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, openldap

I'm currently working on a project where I need to write a lot of items to a LDAP directory. I've now created a parallel foreach loop that creates a new LDAP connection for each contact and adds that contact to the database. When the add function is completed the connection is closed. So for every thread/contact in the parallel foreach loop I create a new LDAP connection.

I was wondering if it isn't possible to create a pool of connections that can be used by the parallel foreach loop. So I can save the cost of setting up a new connection every time.

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: It's possible - see [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-create-an-object-pool). But please be more specific in your questions on SO.

Comment: Thanks @DmytroMukalov, what would you like to have seen more so I can take into account for the next question. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the question like "is it possible" is to broad for an engineering subject - everything is possible the question is only in "costs". Please make sure that you describe the specific problem you'd like to solve and provide a source code when you need either to indicate specific constraints or to find problem in the code (for more information see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).